# Loss of types in the abstract factory

Tags: java, generics, abstract-factory

I am developing an java application that accepts SOAP message. The body of the SOAP contains various documents. From time to time their number varies (depending on the version of the album).

For their analysis I am trying to apply a pattern Abstract Factory.
But my implementation, I ran into a problem:

```
  IAlbumFactory albumFactory = AlbumFactory.buildDocument (Album.A_5_0_12);
```

The first parameter has I can point to any type of enum CustomDocument (although CustomDocument.DO1 only valid Du). And this error only shows up in RunTime

```
  IDocumentEntity <Du, org.w3c.dom.Element> documentEntity =     
  albumFactory.getWorker   (CustomDocument.DO1);
```

how to avoid it?

Some class:

```
public interface IDocumentEntity<T,E> {
T getReport(E e) throws JAXBException ;
}
public interface IAlbumFactory {
IDocumentEntity getWorker(CustomDocument document);
}

/**
 * Class for convert document DO1 (album 5.0.12) from org.w3c.dom.Element to Du
 * entity type
 *
 * @author uas
 */
public class DO1_5_0_12 implements IDocumentEntity<Du, org.w3c.dom.Element> {

protected DO1ReportInType unmarshall(org.w3c.dom.Element e) throws JAXBException {
    DO1ReportInType resultType = null;
    JAXBContext result = JAXBContextHelper_DO1.getJaxbContextInstance();
    Unmarshaller u = result.createUnmarshaller();
    Object c = u.unmarshal(e);
    if (c instanceof JAXBElement) {
        JAXBElement jaxbe = (JAXBElement) c;
        resultType = (DO1ReportInType) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(jaxbe);
    }
    return resultType;
}

@Override
public Du getReport(org.w3c.dom.Element e) throws JAXBException {
    DO1ReportInType dO1Report = unmarshall(e);
    DO1ReportIn_JAXBtoORCL btoORCL = new DO1ReportIn_JAXBtoORCL(dO1Report);
    return btoORCL.getReport();
   }
}
```

Factory for Album 5_0_12.

```
public class AlbumFactory_5_0_12 implements IAlbumFactory {

/**
 * Return documentWorker byn CustomDocument value
 * @param customDocument
 * @return throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
@Override
public IDocumentEntity getWorker(CustomDocument customDocument) {
    IDocumentEntity doc = null;
    switch (customDocument) {
        case DO1:
            doc = new DO1_5_0_12();
            break;
        case DO2:
            doc = new DO2_5_0_12();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("For album 5.0.12 " +       customDocument.DocName() + " not support");
    }
    return doc;
}
```

}

```
public class AlbumFactory {

private AlbumFactory() {
}

public static IAlbumFactory buildDocument(Album album) {
    IAlbumFactory result = null;

    switch (album) {
        case A_5_0_12:
            result = new AlbumFactory_5_0_12();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This version " + album.AlbumName() + " is not support");

    }

    return result;

}
```

}

Comment: And the error is... ?

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. java.lang.ClassCastException. For example IDocumentEntity <Act, org.w3c.dom.Element> documentEntity = albumFactory.getWorker (CustomDocument.DO1); (DO1 must be correspond with Du)